# How can I limitToLast THEN orderByChild?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

**What I'm needing to do is essentially get the Top 10 of the last 50. Or literally limitToLast(50) THEN orderByChild.**

Right now this code works beautifully for getting the top 50 of my ENTIRE LIST(thousands) and reversing it for proper display order but it's sorting the entire list and returning the top 50. I need to sort the top 10 of the last 50 entries.

```
export class DisplayComponent{
  trackFbObjects = (idx, obj) => obj.$key;

  fml: Observable<any>

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {    
    this.fml = db.list('vertigo', ref => ref.limitToLast(50).orderByChild("totalvote")).valueChanges()
    .map((Array) => Array.reverse());
  }

}
```

Then I will pull the 10 out of the 50 using NgFor and NgIf like this:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of (fml | async); let i = index; trackBy:trackFbObjects">
<li *ngIf="i<10"> {{ item.title }}  </li></ul>
```

I was thinking maybe it would be possible to just do the limitToLast(50) and then during the Array.reverse() maybe sort it there by "totalvote"? I have no idea, but I can't find a working solution and any help would be appreciated.

My entries look like this if it helps:

```
     vertigo
       -L9X0AiwPemOIepVm5gf
         -totalvote: "333"
         -title: "Smile."
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs this in the future, I was able to sort my list outside of my query like this:

```
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {    
    this.fml = db.list('vertigo', ref => ref.limitToLast(50)).valueChanges()
    .map((Array) => Array.sort((a, b) => b['totalvote'] - a['totalvote']));
  }
```